# protecting a Zend Framework site from hacking

Tags: security, zend-framework

I have a Zend framework site running and somebody actually managed to upload 2 php scripts in the ZF public folder.

I've changed the password to cpanel including ftp, database etc.

But how can I prevent this from happening again?

Comment: Does your app have some functionality to allow users to upload files? If not, then your issue is likely to be elsewhere.

Comment: yes using ckeditor and pgrfilemanger http://pgrfilemanager.sourceforge.net/ from the password protected admin side using Zenc_Acl

Comment: Okay so your admin site might require a login, but if you paste the  direct URL to pgrfilemanager into a browser is it possible to access that without being logged in?

Comment: i think , that is possible. you can have the whole ckeditor folder and pgrfilemanager as one of its plugin folder from the zend public folder.yes direct url into address bar gives you that access

Comment: Please do not cross post questions. see this [FAQ question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/164367) for guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is possible to access pgrfilemanager without a login then users can easily upload whatever files they want to your site. You'll need to find a way to secure that script, either by including your ZF login check inside of it somehow, or by securing it with a htaccess style login instead (probably easier).

Comment: OK but the script is actually in the public folder.as it's the entry point of the Framework while the pgrfilemanager is inside the public folder tree. public/ckeditor/plugins. while the hacker put the script inside public/ . the permission of public is still 755.
and i've check with the pgrfilemanager, you can go beyond the mapped   folder which is public/images.

so am trying to understand what might have happened.Thank for replying

Comment: It doesn't matter though, they could have uploaded PHP scripts into public/images and you would still have the same problem.